# My code is showing "ValueError: 'label' must be of length 'x'" this error. Why?

Tags: python, label, valueerror

If you want to access the dataset then, here is the link:
[dataset link](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/brllrb/uber-and-lyft-dataset-boston-ma)

```
df["source"].value_counts().reset_index()

src_freq = list(df["source"].value_counts())
src = list(df['source'].unique())
src

def make_autopct(values):
    def my_autopct(pct):
        total = sum(values)
        val = int(round(pct*total/100.0))
        return '{p:.1f}%  '.format(p=pct)
    return my_autopct

plt.show()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(8,8))
ax[0].pie(src_freq,autopct=make_autopct(src_freq), labels = src)

# # Adding legend
# ax[0].legend(title='source',
#             loc="upper right",
#             bbox_to_anchor=(2,1));
ax[0].set_title("Percentage count of source", fontsize=15)

sns.countplot(y='source', data=df, ax=ax[1])
```

I expected my out put to be:
[expected o/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsLJc.png)

but I am getting,
[my o/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQzKu.png)

and this error,
[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nZmO.png)

and after adding 'None' instead of 'src' in labels I am getting,
[o/p after adding None](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2830.png)

Comment: Show errors and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: Thanks for considering in helping me when I ran the code just now so that I can copy the error, it worked and I got the desired result